# Swift & Firestore - check for document in collection always returns false

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

So, here's my code, it's pretty simple...just trying to check if a document with a specific name exists in my firestore collection and return a bool for its staus:

```
 func checkSessionCode(_ code: String) -> Bool {
        print("checkSessionCode running")
        var doesCodeExist = false
        
        
        let docRef = env.db.collection(K.sessions).document(code)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if document!.exists {
                print("Document data: \(document!.data())")
                doesCodeExist = true
              } else {
                 print("Document does not exist")
                doesCodeExist = false
              }
        }
        
        print("doesCodeExist == \(doesCodeExist)")
        return doesCodeExist
    }
```

Long story short, no matter what my input code is (if it matches a document or not), this always returns false. Also, for what its worth, in the console the print("doesCodeExist == (doesCodeExist)") output always prints before the print("Document data: (document!.data())") ...Is there something about this closure that it is returning the value before it finishes checking the server?

Also, my document is really lightweight, so the check happens quick (not quick enough apparently)...

Comment: "...Is there something about this closure that it is returning the value before it finishes checking the server?" the closure doesn't return anything. It's setting a value `doesCodeExist`  by side effect, not by returning. What you're seeing is that the side effect doesn't happen in time, because it runs asynchronously. Search for "return from async swift", and you'll see that this question has been asked thousands of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something about this closure that it is returning the value before it finishes checking the server?

Yes, the closure is executed asynchronously, not immediately. `getDocument` does not block the code, and it *returns* immediately, before the query is complete.  The callback is invoked some time later with the results.  This is to avoid making your code block the UI thread, which would cause your app to become unresponsive during the query.  Read more about [why the Firebase APIs are asynchronous](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

The function, as you have it written now, will always return false, because the initial value of `doesCodeExist` will not change by the time its value is returned.

Comment: This is probably the best answer I am going to get...I took the "doesCodeExists" value and moved it to the observable object of my swiftui project, then had this function just set that value, since the toggle was toggling a display in the project. So, although I couldn't get the above to work, i found a workaround and learned something in the process...thanks again!